# change primefaces autoComplete panel width

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces, autocomplete

primefaces 3.5

Theres a way to change the autocomplete area width without to change the autocomplete inputbox ?

[image]

*I want to expand the gray area (TEXT TOO LONG) without change the input white area.*

**Tried with but it shows me only a horizontal scroll bar:**

```
.ui-autocomplete-panel .ui-autocomplete-table {
   width: 240px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
.ui-autocomplete-panel {
   width: 240px !important;
}
```

Instead of

```
.ui-autocomplete-panel .ui-autocomplete-table {
   width: 240px !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm :) thanks... I tried a lot of settings but with no success. Do you know how can I use this with styleClass="" property of autocomplete ? Thank you so much for helping ....

Comment: `styleClass` is exclusively for the input style but `panelStyleClass` is what you want. And in the CSS : `.YOUR_PANEL_STYLE_CLASS.ui-autocomplete-panel ...`

Comment: thx again. I have tried with .mystyle .ui-autocomplete.... (blank space) between .mystyle and .ui-autocomplete. The correct is your way .mystyle.ui-autocomplete.....